# Let $A=\{ f \in \ell^1\, :\,\text{ for each natural number}\, n\,\text{we have}\, |f(n)|<1/2^n \}$. find the closure of $A$ in $\ell^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $A=\{ f \in \ell^1\, :\,\text{ for each natural number}\, n\,\text{we have}\, |f(n)|<1/2^n \}$.
 find the closure of $A$ in $\ell^1$.

I know the interior of A is empty. for the case of getting closure of 
A.This is very hard for me to understand closure of A. can anyone help me out.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more,

Comment: Consider the set $A=\{(x,y) \mid x<1, y<1\}\subset \mathbb R^2$. What is $\overline A$? You should be able to extend to this question then.

Answer (score 1):

$\ell^1$ is a metric space and its closure equals to the set of all elements that have distance $0$ from $A$. On one side, any element $g$ of 
$$
B:=\{f\in\ell^1:\,\,\forall\,\,n\,\,|f(n)|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\}
$$
has distance $0$ from $A$, because it either in $A$ or a limit of elements in $A$. On the other side, 
$\ell^1\setminus B$ is open (being equal to $\{f\in\ell^1:\,\,\exists n\,\,|f(n)|>\frac{1}{2^n}\}$) and disjoint from $A$, so it is also disjoint from the closure of $A$.
It follows that $B=\bar{A}$.